# Update virtuosos index for fct

Tags: indexing, rdf, sparql, owl, virtuoso

I want to update virtuosos index after removing some graphs.

We are using virtuoso Version: 07.10.3207 to store some .owl files.
Every file is uploaded to an own graph.

I installed the fct package from [virtuoso.openlinksw.com...](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtFacetBrowserInstallConfig) for entity uri lookup

To enable the indexing I executed these commands in isql editor:

```
RDF_OBJ_FT_RULE_ADD (null, null, 'All');
VT_INC_INDEX_DB_DBA_RDF_OBJ ();
urilbl_ac_init_db()
```

like [here](http://www.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtFacetBrowserInstallConfig#Post%20Installation).

The autocomplete widget for entity uri lookup works fine.

But when I remove a graph from the triple store, its uris are still shown in the autocomplete widget, even if I execute `VT_INC_INDEX_DB_DBA_RDF_OBJ ()` again.

Is there a way to update virtuosos index after removing some graphs ?

Is it possible to update just some parts of virtuosos index to only remove indices from removed graph without computing indices for all other rdf stuff ?

Answer (score 1):

Information about the IRIs continues to stay,(inspite of the deletion you performed) that is why you see them in the autocomplete widget. A possible solution will be the autocomplete widget to be tweaked so to check if a given IRI exists in the RDF_Quad .. I have notified our developers so to schedule the tweak in question.

Kind Regards,

Rumi Kocis

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I had a look on the `urilbl_ac_init_db()` function. Looks like the fct search uses the urilbl_complete_lookup_2 table to hold some lables. This table is not updated by dropping a graph.